# Alternative to sys.columns.max_length

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have written the following script to get some data on the columns of a specified table:

```
DECLARE @QueryTable varchar(35);
SET @QueryTable = 'Test';

SELECT DISTINCT
    sys.columns.name AS 'Column',
    sys.types.name AS 'Data type',
    CASE WHEN sys.types.name IN ('varchar', 'char') THEN CAST(sys.columns.max_length AS varchar(5))
    WHEN sys.types.name IN ('decimal', 'numeric') THEN CAST(CAST (sys.columns.precision AS nvarchar(10))  + ', ' + CAST(sys.columns.scale AS nvarchar(10)) AS nvarchar(10))
    WHEN sys.types.name IN ('nvarchar', 'nchar') THEN CAST(sys.columns.max_length / 2 AS varchar(5))
    ELSE '-' END AS 'Max size',
    CASE WHEN sys.columns.is_nullable = 1 THEN 'YES'
    WHEN sys.columns.is_nullable = 0 THEN 'NO' END AS 'Allow nulls',
    CASE WHEN sys.columns.name IN (SELECT Col.COLUMN_NAME from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab, 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col 
WHERE 
    Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.TABLE_NAME
    AND Constraint_Type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
    AND Col.Table_Name = @QueryTable) THEN 'PK'
    ELSE '' END AS 'Primary Key'
FROM 
    sys.columns, sys.types, sys.tables
WHERE
    sys.tables.object_id = sys.columns.object_id AND
    sys.types.system_type_id = sys.columns.system_type_id AND
    sys.types.user_type_id = sys.columns.user_type_id AND
    sys.tables.name = @QueryTable
ORDER BY sys.columns.name
```

Naturally, for **nvarchar** and **nchar** types I get a max_length which is twice the size of the actual maximum character length for that field. My question is, is there anywhere I could directly obtain that actual maximum character length defined when the column was created, without resorting to this indirect calculation?

The approach I have used for outputting data for numeric/decimal types is also kind of a mess in my opinion.

Thank you

Comment: The value in sys.columns (and sys.all_columns) is correct; you are doing the right thing in your query. 
**max_length** is actually the maximum bytes and not characters. Unicode values (nvarchar, nchar) take 2 bytes per character.

See max_length: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

See n[var]char: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Comment: Well, thanks! It looks obvious now, but I've never realized that table contained the exact length I needed.

Comment: Note : INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS is a System View (not a table as such) and msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx says INFORMATION_SCHEMA is an ISO standard, suggesting safety from deprecation, however at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186224.aspx we see :  ** Important ** Do not use INFORMATION_SCHEMA views to determine the schema of an object. The only reliable way to find the schema of an object is to query the sys.objects catalog view. INFORMATION_SCHEMA views could be incomplete since they are not updated for all new features.

Comment: You can use `tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to get columns for temp tables.